# Custom SharePoint online page flicker on load SPFX web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I have created an application customizer extension and put my custom header and footer in that extension which loads fine. I had to hide the OOTB ribbon and left bar as I wanted to have totally customized look.

Everything is working fine, however when I load the page, at first it shows the SharePoint Online OOTB items and then when the extension loads it removes these and shows my header, footer and other components. This is what I see when the page loads first. After that, it loads my custom stuff.

[image]

**Question:** Is there any way to avoid this flicker or jitter effect? Can I hide these and show a blank page before my components get load?

Answer (score 3):

Hiding out-of-the-box elements using custom CSS is not supported. To avoid flickering or unexpected issues, I would not hide the OOTB elements at all.

A good solution might be to add the URL parameter `?env=Embedded` to the end of your SharePoint URL. This hides the main navigation, footer, side navigation (and App bar).

Comment: Thanks Callum. The requirement is to hide all OOTB components and show the custom layout completely. That flicker is something which is destroying overall user experience of our application.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution, that would be supported. If this answer helps, please do remember to upvote or mark the answer as accepted to help inform the community.

Comment: It is indeed a much better approach. Thank you very much for the clue. To some extent it helped me but I am still trying to overcome the Hub Navigation etc. I will keep this question open for another answer, however I have upvoted it already. Thank you very much for this. Appreciate that.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if you feel it answered your question, this will help inform the community.

Comment: This actually did not solve the problem however it was helpful to some extent. Using ?env=Embedded or ?env=WebView do not show these components but also hide other items like Hub Navigation. Also its difficult to use these query parameters each time the user navigates. So let's keep this question open until we find the more suitable option. Thank you a lot for your time and cooperation.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't think there's an answer to it right now but Microsoft could introduce something in the future.